# Bootstrap List Filter problems with Turkish "İ" character

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, filter, special-characters

I use bootstrap list filter ( [see github](https://github.com/stefanocudini/bootstrap-list-filter) ) but I have a problem with Turkish "İ" character, when I type lowercase "i" i got no results.

You can see my code snippet:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
$('#mylist').btsListFilter('#filterinput', {
    itemChild: 'span'
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://labs.easyblog.it/bootstrap-list-filter/bootstrap-list-filter.src.js"></script>

<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
   <input class="form-control" id="filterinput" type="search" placeholder="type istanbul..." />
  </div>
  <div id="mylist" class="list-group">
   <a class="list-group-item" href=""><span>İstanbul</span></a>
   <a class="list-group-item" href=""><span>İzmir</span></a>
   <a class="list-group-item" href=""><span>Ankara</span></a>
   <a class="list-group-item" href=""><span>Hatay</span></a>
   <a class="list-group-item" href=""><span>Teksas</span></a>
   <a class="list-group-item" href=""><span>Newyork</span></a>
   <!-- FILLED DYNAMICALLY -->
  </div>
 </form>
```

Type **istanbul** with lowercase.